# Deserialization Issue by Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I want to deserilize this `Json` to Model, this is the
Json: `[{"dimensions": [ "www "], "metrics ": [{ "values ": [ "2 " ]},{ "values ": [ "0 "]}]}]`

and i create this model to deserialize json to this model:

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public List<string> dimensions { get; set; }
    public List<Metric> metrics { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Metric
{
    public List<string> values { get; set; }
}
```

and using `Newtonsoft` for this:

```
 var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(json);
```

but it doesnot work and give me this error:

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ResultModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly'.

What is the problem?

Comment: Your json is array (starts with "[", ends with "]"), so you should deserialize it to `ResultModel[]`, not to single `ResultModel`.

Comment: `DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to miss that your JSON is really array, even if it contains just one object. So you have to deserialize it to array:

```
var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel[]>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that there will be at most one model, you can do:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>(json).FirstOrDefault();
```

Otherwise, you should deserialize it to a collection of models, as suggested in the comments:

```
// models is an IEnumerable<ResultModel>
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultModel>>(json);
```